# python 3 error: float is required

Tags: python

I didn't understand why I'm getting an error for this line of code:

**test_data**:  array, **sqft_living** : a column.

**In the line I'm adding a new column 'log_sqft_living' which should contain log'sqft_living'**

```
test_data['log_sqft_living'] = log(test_data['sqft_living'][i] for i in range(len(test_data)))
```

After looking for similar message, I found answers that it should be a number that's why we have to format using float(x) but when I used it the error became argument should be a number of a string. Can someone explain to me why those errors occur?

When I try log(test_data['sqft_living'][1] (for a single number) I don't get an error.

Thank you

Comment: test_data is an array

Comment: The position of closing parenthesis looks wrong.  try `log(test_data['sqft_living'][i]) for i in range(len(test_data))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying the `log` function to a generator, but it only will accept a single value. Change the line to a list comprehension (to make it an explicit list) and move the `log` inside the comprehension so that you are applying it to each element:

```
test_data['log_sqft_living'] = [ log(test_data['sqft_living'][i]) for i in range(len(test_data)) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

`<expression> for <variable> in <data set>` - is list comprehension,
you can read more about list comprehension here: http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/

What this means, it that it produces a list structure - while the function `log` expects to get a number. `math.log(x[, base])`

You can maybe restructure your statement like this:
`test_data['log_sqft_living'] = [log(test_data['sqft_living'][i]) for i in range(len(test_data))]`

**Note:** test_data['log_sqft_living'] will contain a list with this example
As you provided no info about the context and what you want to achieve I can't provide a better solution